I'm having trouble identifying this resistor
This is from an air compressor circuit board. I can't find it using a resistor calculator online:


John Flanigan - Hi, FYI if you are asking for that resistor's value because you know it has failed (i.e. measures open-circuit), then you have a problem elsewhere, which caused it to fail. || I'm not trying to solve that repair question (if I'm right about the reason for the question), just trying to help by pointing out that replacing it, even with an identical resistor, won't fix an underlying fault elsewhere. Also note that if you do replace it, as pointed out in the answer you accepted, it must be a identical fusible resistor. An overloaded normal resistor might catch fire.

The resistor is definitely being held backwards. Determining the color is harder (at least for me).
So we have:

BROWN (or ORANGE) GREEN GOLD (1.5Ω or 3.5Ω)
GOLD (+/-5%)
BLACK (fusible)

3.5Ω is possible but not a standard E24 value so I think, given the comments, I would say the preponderance of evidence would point to:
1.5Ω 5% fusible
If the part is still good, of course you can measure it. You have to account for probe resistance with such low values (short the probes and it might read 0.8Ω) then subtract that from the reading.

The colors on the resistor are as this from left to right.  black, gold?, gold? green, pink/orange.. There are five colors.

@AmitM see edit

I wonder if it's Orange, Blue, Gold, Gold, Black. It's possible bad colour balance or heat have faded the blue to a sort of greeny-blue. 3.6R would be a standard E24 value.

@TomCarpenter Agreed, it would be convenient, but I have tried and it doesn't look likely to me (or the RGB eyedropper). Yageo has a 3.5Ω leaded resistor (1%) stocked by Digikey.

I agree it's a stretch. To be fair both 3.5R 1% and 3.6R 1% would be entirely within the tolerance range for a 3.5R 5% in terms of replacement anyway.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany - Hi, FWIW, to my eyes and with the colour temperature I have set on my monitors (YMMV) from right to left I see it as brown, green (or could be blue), gold, gold - which gives obviously a different 1.5 Ω (or 1.6 Ω) value. Since it should be a 5% tolerance (gold) that suggests E24 and both 1.5 Ω and 1.6 Ω are in the E24 series. What do you think?

@SamGibson 1.5Ω would be a standard value, which gives that a higher likelihood. It looks more orange with my monitor but I can see it could be brown. I'm going to go with that.

Thanks for the help. The second band is indeed green. Any idea where I can find a replacement? I can't seem to find it anywhere online

There are many of them (8 types, >50,000 in stock) at Digikey, and probably others such as Mouser, LCSC etc. You'll have to measure the size to get a comparable power rating. Look for "fusible" or "flameproof" and "Metal Oxide Film". In some applications they may have to be non-inductive, but that's another question.
